# Rails Paperclip - skip attachment saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Is there a way to tell paperclip to skip saving attachments in certain cases?  I'm running some background tasks that update a model with paperclip files attached, and it re-saves those attachments after every save.  Is there anyway to bypass this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Paperclip only performs an actual save (i.e. deletes old attachment and writes new attachment) if you update the attachement, but will log `[paperclip] saving attachment` every time a model is saved. It does this because the log message is printed in an `after_save` call back (before it loops through all attachments and flushes any pending writes or deletes). Provided that you aren't assigning a new attachment, you can ignore the `saving attachment` message.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Paperclip.options[:log] = false` ... (from [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#logging)). Better late than never?