# Paperclip working on sign_out via devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, paperclip

I've recently added paperclip to add avatar to the users.

When a user sign out (using devise) I see this in the logs

```
Started DELETE "/signout" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-04 17:23:15 +0200
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#destroy as HTML   Parameters:
{"authenticity_token"=>"rHNBynyk546DcWTpGuARt2bdbSTtKPbw2ls+nDaihO8="}
User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" =
18 LIMIT 1    (0.0ms)  BEGIN [paperclip] Saving attachments.   
(0.0ms)  COMMIT Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
```

my paperclip is really basic..

this in user.rb

```
has_attached_file :avatar,
    :storage => :s3,
    :bucket => ENV['BUCKET'],
    :s3_credentials => {
      :access_key_id => ENV['ACCESS_KEY'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['SECRET_KEY']
    }
```

on user/_form.html.erb

```
<%= f.file_field :avatar %>
```

and on users/show.html.erb

```
<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url %>
```

what is paperclip doing there?
Is there a way to debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4462445/432977

Basically paperclip will call the 'save' method on every attachment every time you update the model. But if no files are queued for delete or write, nothing will happen.